# How to get the number of points of a highchart stacked column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im trying to display the average instead of the total at the top of a stacked column highchart. In order to do so Im trying to set the formatter to return this.total/number of points on that stack
Is there a way to get the number of points on a stack using "this" object (for example the length of a certain array in "this" or something similar)

```
stackLabels: {
              style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',  
              },
              enabled: true,
              formatter:function(){
                  return this.total/this.??;
              }
```

Thanks

Comment: It should be possible to calculate it on your own. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/m28ob7r7/2/

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński Indeed it worked this way!!! I was checking if there is a field in the object itself but your solution suits me well